# CombineLatest does not unsubscribe

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that creates a `user` and a `session`, it also uses `combineLatest` to call another function when both the `user$` and the `session$` observables have been updated:

```js
public createUserAndSession(): void {
  this.userService.createUser(this.form)
  this.sessionService.createSession(this.form)

  combineLatest([this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$]).subscribe(({
    next: ([user, session]) => {
      console.log(user, session)
      this.sessionService.connectHostToSession(user!, session);
    }
  }))
}
```

This works fine:

[image]

but calling this function a second time causes some issues:
[image]

I suppose I have to unsubscribe from the `combineLatest` subscribe, but cannot figure out how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Have the subscription outside of the createUserAndSession so there is only one subscription.

```
sub = combineLatest([this.userService.user$, this.sessionService.session$]).subscribe(({
  next: ([user, session]) => {
    console.log(user, session)
    this.sessionService.connectHostToSession(user!, session);
  }
}));

public createUserAndSession(): void {
  this.userService.createUser(this.form);
  this.sessionService.createSession(this.form);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // Assuming this is Angular, use the end of lifecycle event of your framework
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

You absolutely still need to unsubscribe from this once the component finishes. If this is Angular you need to do it in ngOnDestroy or the end of life cycle event of your framework.

Comment: Hm, I tried that. But now the `next` isn't called at all.

Comment: Then just use a take(1) so the observable completes after it gets the first emission.

Comment: I had hoped that would work, but `take(1)` doesn't take the last emitted items :/

Comment: Have the subscription outside of the createUserAndSession so there is only one subscription.